# Xamarin.Android and Parse

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am writing an app with C# and Xamarin.I am using Parse at the backend.I am currently stuck at point where when a user clicks signup button my app checks for a user with same phone number in parse database.Ideally If app finds app makes a toast of "cannot signup".If it doesn't find a user it signs the user up.
Below is the code I used.

```
    try {

                    var person = await(from userp in ParseUser.Query where userp.Get<string>("Phone")==phone.Text.ToString() select userp).FindAsync();
                    if(person!=null){Toast.MakeText(this,"A user with same mobile number already exist and can't signup",ToastLength.Long).Show();}
                    else{
                    signupprogress = new ProgressDialog (this);
                    signupprogress.SetTitle ("Please Wait");
                    signupprogress.SetMessage ("Signing you up!!");
                    signupprogress.SetCancelable (true);
                    signupprogress.SetProgressStyle (ProgressDialogStyle.Spinner);
                    signupprogress.Show ();
                    ParseUser user = new ParseUser ();
                    user ["Name"] = name.Text.ToString ();
                    user.Username = email.Text.ToString ();
                    user.Email = email.Text.ToString ();
                    user.Password = password.Text;
                    user ["Address"] = Address.Text.ToString ();
                    user ["Phone"] = phone.Text.ToString ();
                    await user.SignUpAsync ();
                    signupprogress.Dismiss ();
                    var inte = new Intent (this, typeof(LogIn));
                    StartActivity (inte);
                    Toast.MakeText (this, "Signed Up successfully.Please Login", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
                    }       

                } catch (Exception ep) {
                    Toast.MakeText (this, "Some erroroccured "+ ep.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show ();

                }
```

The problem I am facing is:

1. I am able to signup with same number many times.  If person object
   is not null which I think should be the case if my app finds person
   with same phone number the app should show the toast.
2. If I use a different number which is not there in database then I am not able to sign up.

Please help.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FindAsync` will never return `null`. It always returns a `Task<IEnumerable<T>>`. And the result of this task is never `null` either. If it doesn't find anything, it will return an empty list.
Because you are using `await` you don't actually have to deal with the task. You just have to check if it returned any objects.

So what you want to do is this:

```
var persons = await (from userp in ParseUser.Query
                     where userp.Get<string>("Phone")==phone.Text.ToString()
                     select userp).FindAsync();

if(!persons.Any())
{
    Toast.MakeText(this,
                   "A user with same mobile number already exist and can't signup",
                   ToastLength.Long)
         .Show();
}
```